# Jenkins unable to kill process using taskkill windowtitle

Tags: jenkins, cmd, taskkill

While running a windows batch command from Jenkins Im unable to kill a process using taskkill windowtitle. I just get the following error:

```
INFO: No tasks running with the specified criteria.
```

If I write the same script on my own on my computer in CMD it works fine, and if I kill the process by name in Jenkins it works as well. Just cant kill by window title in Jenkins, which is what I have to do in this case.

My batch command is:

```
taskkill /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Start*"
```

Comment: What does tasklist show? Stumbled upon this thread five years after the fact, but I'm sure others will run into similar situations. The tasklist output may be a clue to whoever needs to troubleshoot this next.